# Best materials for printing mountains

Tags: 3d-models, print-material, dimensional-accuracy

Can you suggest me some good material choices for printing some mountains models for educational and fun purposes?

My goal is to mantain the best accuracy without spending too much, I have many models to print: they don't need to be super-resistant.

I was thinking about High-Detail Resin or simple PLA / Recycled rPLA.
I also checked Rigid Resin and Color-Changing PLA.

Here are some examples of my models:
[image: mountain 1]
[image: mountain 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Material is not really going to affect the accuracy unless you're using very exotic things like lightweight foaming materials where the expansion is variable. You don't even have overhangs. So accuracy is pretty much entirely a function of the process, the quality of your machine, and the settings you use.

Resin will generally have higher resolution than FDM if that's what you're looking for. With FDM you can increase resolution somewhat by using a smaller nozzle, but that will make large prints like this very slow. Within the broad classes of resin or FDM, though, which specific resin or which specific polymer or color or brand you use is not going to make a difference. Pick the one that meets your aesthetic needs.